# Sticky header with scrolling background

Tags: html, css, background-image

I made a (sticky) header for one of my clients.
The background is fixed. So when the page is scrolled, the background seems to slide behind the element. Until the header sticks.

My client wants the background to still scroll through the element (with the page scroll), when the header is sticked to the top.

```
header {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    background-image: url( '../img/background.png' );
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

header.sticky {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Anyone an idea on how to do this?

The pseudo elements ::before and ::after are already in use.

Comment: Can you link to the website?

Answer (score 0):

set the background image on a container that can be scrolled. Like body of a document. With position: relative.

```
body { background: url(...); position: relative; }
```

Then set the fixed element with position fixed.

```
header.stickOnTop { position:fixed; top:0px; }
```

To make the background went through, set the backgeound of the sticky element at opaque or completely transparent.

```
header.stickyOnTop{ opacity: 0.5; }
```